# How to get list of users with a given group as primary group

Tags: group, ldap, getent

With

```
getent group xyz
```

I get a list of users who are members of `xyz` with `xyz` either as a primary group **or** as secondary group.

How do I get a list of just those users who have `xyz` as their primary group?

My users are in LDAP, so I am not looking for solutions which involve parsing `/etc/group`.

Comment: If you run `getent passwd`, do you get the full list of users including all LDAP users? If so, you can use solutions that work by parsing `/etc/passwd`. Note that primary group membership is not defined in `/etc/group`.

Comment: ```getent passwd``` does indeed give me all the LDAP users, so I could parse the output. You're also right about ```/etc/group```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think you can do any better than retrieving each member user’s information:

```sh
groupinfo="$(getent group xyz)"
groupinfo="${groupinfo#*:*:}"
gid="${groupinfo%%:*}"
members="${groupinfo##*:}"
(IFS=,; set -f; for member in $members; do
 getent passwd $member | grep -E "([^:]+:){3}$gid:"
 done)
```

If your LDAP server allows you to enumerate all users with `getent passwd`, you could parse that instead after determining the gid:

```sh
groupinfo="$(getent group xyz)"
groupinfo="${groupinfo#*:*:}"
gid="${groupinfo%%:*}"
getent passwd | grep -E "([^:]+:){3}$gid:"
```